# dotnet dev-certs certificate not trusted

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, https

I am working through Adam Freeman's book "Pro ASP.Net Core 3".  I have gotten to the introduction to https.  He instructs us to use Powershell and run these commands in this order

```
dotnet dev-certs https --clean
dotnet dev-certs https --trust
```

When I run the `clean` command, I get a message saying

> "HTTPS development certificates successfully removed from the machine."

But when I run the trust command, I get:

> "A valid HTTPS certificate with a key accessible across security
> partitions was not found. The following command will run to fix it:
> 'sudo security set-key-partition-list -D localhost -S
> unsigned:,teamid:UBF8T346G9'
> This command will make the certificate key accessible across security
> partitions and might prompt you for your password. For more
> information see: https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/2.1/troubleshootcertissues
>
> A valid HTTPS certificate with a key accessible across security
> partitions was not found. The following command will run to fix it:
> 'sudo security set-key-partition-list -D localhost -S
> unsigned:,teamid:UBF8T346G9'
> This command will make the certificate key accessible across security
> partitions and might prompt you for your password. For more information
> see: https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/3.1/troubleshootcertissues
>
> Trusting the HTTPS development certificate was requested. A
> confirmation prompt will be displayed if the certificate was not
> previously trusted. Click yes on the prompt to trust the certificate.
> There was an error trusting HTTPS developer certificate."

I tried

- running `dotnet dev-certs https` results in "A valid HTTPS certificate is already present."
- running powershell as administrator. But I got the same errors. The book says I may get a couple of dialog boxes, but I did not get them.
- `dotnet --version`  gives me 3.1.200.

What do I have to do to get the certificate to work?

Comment: `A valid HTTPS certificate is already present.` It seems that the developer certificate has been generated, you can try to manually trust the certificate with the **ASP.NET Core HTTPS development certificate** friendly name by copying from **Current User > Personal > Certificates** into **Current User > Trusted root certification authorities > Certificates** within the certificate manager UI. Then check if it works for you.

Comment: `Great! That worked!` Hi @ROBERTRICHARDSON, glad to hear the workaround did help resolve the problem. I write a post, and you can accept it as answer, which would help other community members quickly find this case and resolve similar issue.

Comment: I'm getting the same circular block....but on a Mac.  (I am not a Mac fan, but in our hybrid java/dotnet-core environment, developers are issued Macs as the PC network policies are so tightly locked down).  Why is my computer lying to me?? :). "HTTPS development certificates successfully removed from the machine."

Comment: Future readers.  Someone shows a "bigger hammer" idea here : https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/14581#issuecomment-535280484. dotnet tool uninstall --global dotnet-dev-certs
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-dev-certs
dotnet dev-certs https --trust      (It is not working for Mac, FYI, but I saw it .. so left a breadcrumb here)

Answer (score 37):

Ok...I found a MAC super hint at the github link below.

(It ~might translate to the PC side...but I cannot test that)

https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/10422

> Encountered the same issue on macOS. As a solution, in the keychain,
> remove the old localhost certificate under 'System' and recreate it
> via the dotnet commands described in the docs. It will be placed under
> 'login'.

So to better describe the above quote, I've added a screen shot here (image below with the magenta/fuchsia/pinkish circles), to provide a "here is where it is on the Mac".....of what the text above describes..

So my steps were:

```
dotnet dev-certs https --clean

dotnet dev-certs https --check

// (DO THE MANUAL keychain-old-localhost removal NOW (image below) 
// (before running the below terminal commands)

dotnet dev-certs https --check

dotnet dev-certs https 

dotnet dev-certs https --trust
```

[image]

Comment: This worked perfectly!
I never would have figured this out on my own.

Comment: @MerkleGroot I hear ya.  You feel like you're in a Minotaur occupied Labyrinth...trying to get it corrected.  Please report back if you were Mac or PC.

Comment: This was a Mac and I'm far from a Mac expert.

Comment: Mac is my least (and emphasis on least) preferred O/S.  I'll run win10, and I'll run "real linux" (ubuntu for example..with "cinnamon"). but mac o/s, not a fan.  However, my current company, developers get "admin rights" on macs, but not pc's.  So I gotta live on one out of necessity.

Comment: Works well- but on Windows 11, required a Windows restart after the --trust step.

Answer (score 8):

> What do I have to do to get the certificate to work?

For some reason, dotnet CLI might throw exception while we use `dotnet dev-certs https --trust` command to trust the HTTPS development certificate.

As a workaround, we can try following steps to manually trust the certificate.

1. Run `dotnet dev-certs https` command to generate a HTTPS certificate (if you do not generate it)
2. Copy  the certificate with the **ASP.NET Core HTTPS development certificate** friendly name by copying from **Current User > Personal > Certificates** into **Current User > Trusted root certification authorities > Certificates** within the certificate manager UI, like below.

   [image]

Comment: For me this worked
1) using `certmgr.msc`  backup all `localhost` certificates under  `Personal` and then remove them  
2)  `dotnet dev-certs https` resulted in `A valid HTTPS certificate with a key accessible across security partitions was not found...`
3)  i copied a still valid `ASP.NET Core HTTPS development certificate` from **Current User > Trusted root certification authorities > Certificates** to **Current User > Personal > Certificates**
This worked at least that much that `dotnet run` worked

Answer (score 5):

The below command worked for me

- dotnet dev-certs https --clean
- dotnet dev-certs https --trust

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is a tricky issue, and I've tried several methods without luck for ASP.NET Core website project. I'm using VS Code on a Mac (macOS 12.6.7).

When I run the following commands in the VS Code terminal, it worked for me:

- Ensure a clean ASP.NET Core project: `dotnet clean`
- Clear existing certificate: `dotnet dev-certs https --clean`
- Create a fresh certificate: `dotnet dev-certs https --trust`

Now I was able to run the project with `dotnet run` and reloading the browser.

PS: If you're lazy, you can also chain the commands like this: `dotnet clean && dotnet dev-certs https --clean && dotnet dev-certs https --trust`

Answer (score 0):

For me on Windows 10 running Visual Studio 2022 all I had to do was

`dotnet dev-certs https --clean`

Then I rebooted my PC and opened my solution again. When running the solution I got the "trust the VS cert" dialog box like I should have the first time I ran my project.

Everything works now and I can run my project.